# data type of "data" in call back function in ajax after server response in ajax-php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**what is the data type of data in call back function in php ajax after server response**

Example:

```
$('#ff').form({
    success:function(data){
        alert(**data**);
    }
});
```

Comment: It depends on the headers set on the page that you are calling in ajax

Comment: Yo can specify the type in dataType argument  in the ajax call. like dataType:'html'

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `content-type` of the HTTP response, unless you tell jQuery to ignore what the server says what the data is with a `dataType` property on the Ajax options object.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) describes it thus:

> The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter

and

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are…

Comment: it was  asked for a interview... i said it depends, but the interviewer keep on insisting to predict the type of data returned thru ajax call

Comment: If you have enough information about the software generating the response, then you can predict it.

Answer (score 0):

its depends what you specify in dataType in ajax call like if you write dataType : 'json' then it would be json.

Comment: No, if you write `JSON` then it will give you the results of parsing the JSON into a JavaScript object